# Let's point to REL attribute instead of .val

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that checked or not relatively to the select menu.

It works if i set the value on each option menu, but i would like to don't use the value (.val) but the rel attribute. Is it possible?

```
<div>
    <form method="GET" action"">
<select name="stock" id="stock" value="">
<option value="PAUL" rel="1" selected>PAUL</option>
<option value="MARIE" rel="0" >MARIE</option>
<option value="LUKE"rel="1" >LUKE</option>
</select>

    
<input type="checkbox" name="stock[]" class="stockclass" value="1" checked> STOCK
    
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
    <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#stock').change(function () {
         var dID = $(this).find(":selected").val();  
         
         $('.stockclass').prop('checked', false).filter(function(){
   return this.value === dID;
             
}).prop('checked', true);
     });     
 });
    </script>
```

Jsfiddle:
[Jsfillde demo code](https://jsfiddle.net/y4bk0s9n/)

Answer (score 0):

[`option`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-option-element) elements don't have a `rel` attribute.

You could use a [`data-*` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) like `data-rel`:

```html
<option value="PAUL" data-rel="1" selected>PAUL</option>
<!--                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^                    -->
```

Then you get it via `attr` or `data`:

```js
const dID = $(this).find(":selected").attr("data-rel");
//                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or

```
const dID = $(this).find(":selected").data("rel");
//                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(Note that `data` is *not* just an accessor for `data-*` attributes, but it would work here. Still, when all I want is the simple value in the attribute, I use `attr`.)

Comment: i just add jsfiddle demo code.. can you help me to adapt?

Comment: @developmentcpm2022 - I think you can do it with the information above.